Hi I'm curious how the spellslinger works? I.e. can I play it as a universalist or not?
I'm building a character for Pathfinder 1e planning on multiclassing as a wizard (spellslinger) / rogue (chameleon) ultimately as a sniper.

So I suspect the source of the confusion is this statement:

A wizard that does not select a school receives the universalist school instead.

which is found in the first paragraph of the description for the wizard’s arcane school feature.
The thought being that when the spellslinger’s school of the gun feature says

This ability replaces arcane school.

does that mean that a spellslinger is a wizard who has not selected a spell school, i.e. they should receive the universalist school?
And the answer to that is “No.” Because school of the gun replaces arcane school, the first quotation effectively does not appear anywhere in your class features: it’s part of a class feature, arcane school, that you don’t have. Or, from another perspective, you don’t receive the universalist school, because you are not “A wizard that [did] not select a school”—you selected the school of the gun.
So no, you do not—and cannot—gain the universalist school features as a spellslinger.
Overall, the spellslinger archetype is kind of meh. Pathfinder firearms are annoying and painful to use, and most of the gunslinger class is dedicated to mitigating or fixing those pain points. The spellslinger archetype gives you some, but not all, of those gunslinger fixes, so your firearms are still awkward. And ultimately, spells are just vastly stronger than guns are. That said, it’s not unplayable or anything. If you want to be a mage with a gun, it’s the way to go.
On the other hand, rogue—chameleon or otherwise—doesn’t tend to add very much here: sneak attack can work with spells or gunshots, but ultimately you’ll get more damage by just having stronger spells, and every rogue level is a level you’re not progressing towards higher spell levels. Sneak attacking at range is also kind of awkward, because the best way to trigger sneak attack is by flanking, which doesn’t work with ranged attacks. Usually for more of a magical rogue, you’d go with eldritch scoundrel, which is pretty good, but obviously doesn’t have the spellslinger features you want. Personally, I’d suggest just nixing rogue. (If you are gonna do it anyway, chameleon is fine—it’s not amazing, but it doesn’t cost a ton, either.)
Oh, and if you do take any rogue levels—chameleon, eldritch scoundrel, or whatever—make sure it’s the rogue unchained. The core rogue is pretty poor. The unchained one is pretty solid. Wizard is still way better, though.
